# Visual Studio Code can't find files inside vendor folder (Laravel project)

Tags: visual-studio-code, laravel-5.5

I'm working with Laravel 5.5 and I use Visual Studio Code for code editor. After last update, VS Code freaked out. The main problem is that I can't search files inside `vendor` folder with ctrl+p. I can search and find any files except inside `vendor` folder. Does `vendor` folder disallow searching? I can't find anything related to this. Does anyone have a similar problem? Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked what's the default preset for `search.exclude` in your settings?

Comment: @RamizWachtler,  yes, I did, `"search.exclude": {
    "**/node_modules": true,
    "**/bower_components": true
  },`

Comment: `"search.useIgnoreFiles": false` worked for me.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

**Fix 1**.

I am not sure how many projects you have but I think you can enable this by changing the excludefile settings.

1. Go to VSCode > Preferences > Settings or press ⌘,.
2. Search for **files.exclude** and make **/.git to false.

**Fix 2**

OR try to search for **search.useIgnoreFiles** in your settings and make it false.

You can find more details [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/40918).

Comment: Nothing changed :| Still can dive into vendor file with `ctrl+P`

Comment: fix 2 is the one

Comment: Fix 1 can solve problems too. In laravel for example you may have the `resources\views\vendor\ ` directory that should NOT be ignored. However, by default vscode ignores ALL `vendor` directories. Changing `**/vendor` with `/vendor` allows to ignore only the npm vendor directory in the root path.

Comment: What is the purpose of ignoring `**/.git`? Seems unrelated to me.

Comment: Fix 1 makes no sense - OP is asking about `vendor` directory, not `.git`

Answer (score 22):

- Open User Settings
- Search for: "Search: Use Ignore Files"
- Uncheck: "Controls whether to use .gitignore and .ignore files when searching for files."