# When using CTRL-P Doesnt Search ALL project files

Tags: visual-studio-code

Ctrl P seems to ignore every directory inside of the public folder in our works laravel project. it sees the files inside the public directory but ignores the other directories in there. I've checked out the user settings for vs code and I found one solution that said to set `"search.useIgnoreFiles": true` to `false` which works ! but now that makes all the node files etc come up which is added cluter, if theirs a work around to have it see the folders in the public directory that'd be great I just cant seem to find one. My googling skills are not strong enough

Comment: `"search.exclude"` ?

Comment: "search.exclude": {
    "**/node_modules": true,
    "**/bower_components": true
  } @Alex

Comment: `node files` - is it the files from **node_modules** folder or something else? What are you trying to do? Just add files or folders that you don't want to see to this object - `search.exclude`.

Comment: This worked for me
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47918689/visual-studio-code-cant-find-files-inside-vendor-folder-laravel-project

Comment: @Ritin thanks buddy Ill give it ago